Conditional and random coefficients/mixed logit models with no alternative-specific constant terms (ASCs)
How would the interpretations of some alternative-specific variables change if alternative-specific constants (ASCs) are not included, and what possible justification can one provide on why alternative-specific constants may not be necessary in both models? 
What do alternative-specific constants do in both regression types generally?
